# Error 1004 vba excel when entering vlookup formula into cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried everything, including reading many questions in the forum about Error 1004 Application Defined or Object-Defined Error, but I can't find anything that is helping me fix the error. It writes the correct formula in the Immediate window.Here is the code. I've put where I get the error in the code.

The variable definitions are the following, and I've included the values in the watch window at the time of the Error 1004

```
Dim templateName As String       ' = "Company 1"   and yes this worksheet exists in my file
Dim servicesRow As Integer       ' = 22
Dim j as Integer                 ' = 1
Public firstProjectSOF as Range  ' firstProjectSOF.Row = 5
Dim columnTemp As Variant        ' columnTemp(0) = "A"
Public lastProjectSOF as Range   ' lastProjectSOF.Row = 65
Dim Rng as Range                 ' Rng.Column = 17



For j = 1 To numEmployees

    With Sheets("SOF").Range("E5", Range("E5").End(xlToRight))       'Finds the cell in SOF of that employee's last name
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=employees_lastName(j), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    End With
    'This is where the error 1004 occurs, on trying to write the VLOOKUP formula into the cell

    Sheets(templateName).Range(Cells(servicesRow + 1 + j, 5)).FormulaLocal = "=VLOOKUP($G$10,'Staff Output Final'!B" & firstProjectSOF.Row & ":" _
    & columnTemp(0) & lastProjectSOF.Row & "," & (Rng.Column - 1) & ",FALSE)"
Next
```

For info, if it is relevant, my computer is a Mac from Canada (English), but I recently edited the file on a PC computer in France (with OS in French).  Just in case that was creating problems, I just tried creating a new excel file on my Mac in and copying and pasting the tabs from the old file into the new one, but I am still getting the Error 1004...

Thanks for any help! Much appreciated!

Comment: Where do you initialize `lastProjectSOF`?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "initialize"? Do you mean "where I assign it values"? I use an input box, Set lastProjectSOF = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="In Staff Output Final, select the last cell in column B that has a project number", Title:="STAFF OUTPUT FINAL, Last Cell in Range", Type:=8)

Comment: I just added the information that `lastProjectSOF` is a Public variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I just tried something by chance and it worked.... I removed Range, and just left the Cells part, so the code became:

```
Sheets(templateName).Cells(servicesRow + 1 + j, 5).FormulaLocal = "=VLOOKUP($G$10,'Staff Output Final'!B" & firstProjectSOF.Row & ":" _
& columnTemp(0) & lastProjectSOF.Row & "," & (Rng.Column - 1) & ",FALSE)"
```

I'm not quite sure why this works, but it does....

Does anyone know why???  Since higher up in the same code, I use the following code to assign a VLOOKUP formula to another cell, and it worked with "Range" no problems.

```
Sheets(templateName).Range("A18:H18").FormulaLocal = "=VLOOKUP($G$10,'PEIINV2 - paste here'!B" & firstProjectPEIINV.Row & ":AH" & lastProjectPEIINV.Row & _
",2,FALSE)"
```

Comment: The required Cell1 of the range object must be an A1 style reference if you only have a single argument; your Cells argument returns a range object.  Read HELP for the Worksheet.Range Property, but it is confusing.  If you used something like range(cells(1,1).address)  it would work, but not range(cells(1,1))

Comment: Thanks Ron, yes you are right that it works with the range(cells(1,1).address).  I appreciate the explanation since I tried reading about the properties of Range and Cells online but didn't find anything that would have tipped me off.  It could just be that I missed it.  In any case, thanks again! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets(templateName).Range(Cells(servicesRow + 1 + j, 5))
```

Your starting code misses a sheets(templatename) before cells(...), so if the activesheet is not templateName, it could trigger mistakes.

You might also want to change

```
With Sheets("SOF").Range("E5", Range("E5").End(xlToRight))
```

to

```
With Sheets("SOF").Range("E5", sheets("SOF").Range("E5").End(xlToRight))
```